# $f_n \in C([0, 1])$, does there exist $(a, b)$, $p \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\sup_\limits{x \in (a, b)} |f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n > p$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

Assume that $f_n \in C([0, 1])$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $x \in [0, 1]$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist a nonempty interval $(a, b)$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that$$\sup_{x \in (a, b)} |f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$$for any $n > p$?

Here, $C([0, 1])$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions defined on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you are asking if we can find a sub-interval of $[0,1]$ where the convergence is uniform.  Is that right?

Comment: @user46944  Not really.  If the $\epsilon$ changes then the interval $(a,b)$ may have to change.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Good point.

Comment: Is $C[0,1]$ the class of all continuous maps on $[0,1]$ or all continuously differentiable maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is continuous. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider
$$
G_k := \{x \in [0,1] : |f_k(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon/2\}
$$
and set
$$
F_n = \cap_{k=n}^{\infty} G_k = \{x \in [0,1] : \sup_{k\geq n}|f_k(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon/2 \}
$$
Then $F_n$ is closed and by pointwise convergence
$$
[0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n
$$
So by Baire Category, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N$ has non-empty interior, and so $\exists$ an open interval $J \subset F_N$ such that for any $k\geq N$
$$
\sup_{x\in J} |f_k(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon/2 < \epsilon \qquad (\ast)
$$
If $f$ is not continuous, I am not sure, but I hope this helps.

Edit: As pointed out by @B.S. Thomson in the comments, even if $f$ is not continuous, the proof can be fixed by taking
$$
F_n := \{x\in [0,1] : \sup_{k,j\geq n}|f_k(x) - f_j(x)| \leq \epsilon/2\}
$$
we obtain an open interval $J$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in J}|f_k(x) - f_j(x)| \leq \epsilon/2 \quad\forall k,j\geq N
$$
Now by pointwise convergence, we get $(\ast)$

Comment: Maybe adjust the proof by using $F_n$ as the set of all points $x$ for which $$ |f_k(x) - f_j(x)| \leq \epsilon/2 $$ for all $k$ and $j$ greater than $n$?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: Thanks! Have edited the post to reflect this.